# Wordpress cropping image - infinity

Tags: wordpress, image, crop

When I try to crop an image inside "Edit Image" it says infinity at the Selection (see image below) Then I'm not able to crop the image. When I rotate the image and rotate it back, then I'm able to crop it again.

[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score -1):

I had to remove the line:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE');
```

That was in my `lib/extras.php`, after that it worked. Don't ask me why.